# How can I allow only gmail.com as domain in my email field validating using jquery-validation plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I allow only gmail.com as domain in my email field validating using jquery-validation plugin ?

```
$("#myForm").validate({
rules: {
    myemail: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
    }
}
});
```

Comment: To restrict to gmail must have a specific use case scenario, so typically you just want to write a regular expression.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514382/override-jquery-validate-plugin-email-address-validation refer This Link There is a Solution

Comment: @babtech,  please award someone with the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You can accept gmail like this below,  notice I added in for it to ignore .org and .net as well you can keep tweaking your regex to exactly how you want it.

```
\w*\@(?!org)(?!net)[g][m][a][i][l]
```

**Edit based on Sparky's** :  CASE -- Uppercase and 3 letter email name @gmail.com

```
$(document).ready(function () {

jQuery.validator.addMethod('gmail', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){3,}@[Gg][Mm][Aa][Ii][Ll]\.com$/i.test(value);
}, "not a valid Gmail email address");

$('#myform').validate({
    rules: {
        field1: {
            required: true,
            gmail: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
        alert('valid form');
        return false;
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the Gmail regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16201085/594235) and use it within [the `addMethod` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to create a new custom rule called "gmail"...

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('gmail', function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^[a-z0-9](\.?[a-z0-9]){5,}@gmail\.com$/i.test(value);
}, "not a valid Gmail email address");

$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        myemail: {
            required: true,
            gmail: true
        }
    }
});
```

It does not matter if you call `.validate()` before or after the `.addMethod()` method.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/fPFpF/**

Answer (score -1):

You have to write a regular expression that accepts strings ending with 'gmail.com'

Check here for regex on Gmail address:

[Regular Expression - Validate Gmail addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200965/regular-expression-validate-gmail-addresses)

Check here on how to add regexp validation:

[jQuery validate: How to add a rule for regular expression validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280759/jquery-validate-how-to-add-a-rule-for-regular-expression-validation)

Comment: It didn't work actually, sorry. I updated my answer with a question that was already solved on stackoverflow.

Comment: Can somebody add a fiddle for this