# Require Domain on Email Address jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery, email, jquery-validate

I'm using the following code (with [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org))  to validate an email address:

```
    $(".schedule-tour-form").validate({
        rules: {    
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }       
        },
    });

    <input id="email" name="Email" class="email" type="email" placeholder="name@email.com" />
```

Problem is it still allows emails without domain suffixes. For example it validates "test@test" 
How to I require a domain suffix?

Comment: can we see the HTML for the form element please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official page of plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/email-method/), even consider `test@test` as a valid mail, then I suppose that this is intended. You could create a new rules, with a strict regex pattern, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12514519/700209).

```
//custom validation rule
$.validator.addMethod("customemail", 
    function(value, element) {
        return /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value);
    }, 
    "Sorry, I've enabled very strict email validation"
);
```

Then to your rules add:

```
rules: {
                    email: {
                        required:  {
                                depends:function(){
                                    $(this).val($.trim($(this).val()));
                                    return true;
                                }   
                            },
                        customemail: true
                    },
```

Comment: The regex in the answer did not work for me. Turned out that hyphen has special meaning in the regex syntax so need to escape it. Updated Regex: /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-+])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(value);

Comment: above regex is not working. use this instead: /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/

Comment: lol. This has exactly the same problem as the OP: it allows emails without domain suffixes, ie. `myemail@something` is allowed