# jQuery Validate - Email without top level domain valid?

Tags: jquery, validation

i have the following input in my form:

```
<input class="input-group-field" id="email" name="email" type="email" size="1" required="">
```

I am using jQuery validation plugin to validate the form before an ajax request.
It works fine, BUT why the hell is this email input valid:

> abc@esd

So if I am not adding a top level domain it seems to be a valid email?

whereas a abc@esd. is invalid

Any Idea whats wrong or what I can do to prevent this?

The code:

```
 if ($("#valForm").valid()) {
   // Do Stuff
 }
```

I have not set up any rules

Thanks

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27529706/require-domain-on-email-address-jquery-validation

Comment: @Bgl86 please put your jquery code also.

Answer (score 5):

Create a custom method:

```
$.validator.addMethod('emailtld', function(val, elem){
    var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

    if(!filter.test(val)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}, '*');
```

Then you can add the data attribute "data-rule-emailtld" to your input field:

```
<input class="input-group-field" id="email" name="email" type="email" size="1" required="" data-rule-emailtld="true">
```

Note: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37610113/93216) from "Sharukh k shaji" use the proper regular expression but wasn't using jQuery Validation plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="input-group-field" id="email" name="email" type="email" size="1" required="">
```

The above code validates whether the entered is email or not. That means it only looks for a '@' and some values before and after that.

To validate email you must do jquery validation by yourself.

```
var emailValidation = function ( email ) {
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

if ( !filter.test( email ) ) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}}
```

The above code is a sample for email validation using regx and jquery.

Comment: Question said it's using jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly, yes, a quick lookup on wikipedia yields interesting results as to what is allowed: [Valid adresses as by wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Valid_email_addresses)

Then again, should you allow everything the RFC spec allows? Probably not. Firstly, because some are pretty specific (local domain only, your example) and others are blatantly obscure like `"()<>[]:,;@\\\"!#$%&'*+-/=?^_{}| ~.a"@example.org` (extracted from wikipedia), secondly validating by the book (or in this case, the RFC) gives you a page-long regex nobody can read nor understand.

Since you're probably using an out-of-the-box feature it's up to you how to handle it. If you want to tweak it, go for a regex that is compliant with 99.8% of all adresses in the wild, and probably 100% of your customers. If not, just accept the inherent weirdness that is the email-adress.

Code-wise, other answers might provide more help on the "how to" matter, since I lack knowledge in that area.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression `/^([\w-.]+@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)(\.+)?[a-zA-Z])\/?/` and create validator methods

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.validator.methods.email = function( value, element ) {
     var email = /^([\w-.]+@(gmail|yahoo|hotmail)(\.+)?[a-zA-Z])\/?/;
    return email.test(value);
  }
  $('.validate').validate();

  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form class="validate">
  <input class="input-group-field" id="email" name="email" type="email" required="">
  <input class="input-group-field" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit"  >
 </form>
```

Comment: Hi Ankur. This looks great at the first look. But how should the regex look like, if I want to allow any domain, nut just gmail yahoo and hotmail?